# Regarding: Child Class in a Array C++

Tags: c++

**Regarding: Child Class in a Array C++**

Hi guys, sorry as i am stuck on some work.

Basically this is what happen

I have a parent class call vehicle and it got 2 child class call

```
Car and Motorcycle
```

Parent class have the following value:

```
string Name: value either Car or MotorCycle
wheels : 4 or 2 (depends is car or motorcycle)
Notes On Wheel:
wheel[0] : Fine condition
wheel[1] : need some repair
wheel[2] : Fine condition
wheel[3] : Fine condition
```

I wonder how do i record this all in  VehicleTwoD Array

Car / Motorcycle is a child class of Vehicle, what do you guys suggest. I try to create an object of VehicleTwoD vehtwod[100];

then i do a for loop to prompt. but how do i record the object car / motorcycle into my VehicleTwoD array and how do i record the string array inside too. so every VehicelTwoD array element contains the information

```
Name ( Motorcycle or Car)
Wheel ( depend on name - 2 or 4)
String array - notes size depend on what is choosen
```

How do i record all in 1 array.

Thank you very much , i know this is polymorphic and i know this is OOP and i know i need study more. but i really stuck on this part on creating such array that can hold other array.

**THANKS!**

Comment: with base-class of `Vehicle` and derived classes of `Car` or `Motorcycle`, your array must be either of pointers (or smart pointers, ideally) to objects. Without pointers (or references, but that isn't applicable for this problem) you will not gain the polymorphism I believe you're looking for.

Comment: @WhozCraig - that looks like an answer.

Comment: @Robᵩ John already has pretty much what I would have done anyway, go with that.

Answer (score 2):

Simplifying solution by not addressing irrelevant dimensionality of the storage array.

Create an array of `Vehicle` pointers, and store those:

```
vector<unique_ptr<Vehicle>> vehicles_;
vehicles_.push_back(new Car(...));
vehicles_.push_back(new Motocycle(...));
```

Since we're using `unique_ptr` here instead of a raw pointer, there's no need to explicitly `delete`.

By making the class [polymorphic](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Classes/Polymorphism) you can declare functions on the base class and implement class-spefici functionality by providing definitions in the derived classes.  This makes it possible to call methods through a pointer to the base class without having to cast to the derived type.

If you need to call methods that exist only on a derived class, then you will need to cast the pointer.  This should be done using [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast), and requires that your class is polymorphic.

EDIT:

Your comments suggest that you don't know how to use a `vector` and would prefer to use a raw array.  That's fine too.  Here's a simplified example that uses a C-style array of raw pointers.  Note that by using neither `vector` nor a smart pointer like `unique_ptr` you make your code more brittle and prone to errors, and you often have to use a [Magic Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) for the array size (which is gross).

```
Vehicle* vehicles_[100];
vehicles_[0] = new Car(...);
vehicles_[1] = new Motorcycle(...);
```

Comment: is there other way i can do this with array instead of vector ?

Comment: Sure, you can use a raw array.

Comment: i not sure how i can use vector in my case, like how to declare it at class and .h level etc